# Finding the edge pixels on only one side of the object

Tags: edge-detection

For my work on lung images, I get a binary image mostly resembling the pattern shown below. I need to find the pixels on the borders shown by yellow arrows. The edges on the other end are shown in pink color. 
[image: The task is to find the pixels on the side of the pattern shown by the arrows]

the edge function on MATLAB highlights all the edges irrespective of the side.

```
edge_BW_portionR = edge(BW_portionR)
```

I also used distance transform in which the lower right corner was used as a reference , and with respect to that, I put some conditions, but in vain.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to detect the right hand side edge with MATLAB:

1.- acquiring image

```
A=imread('001.jpg');
figure(1);imshow(A)
```

[image]

```
A1=A(:,:,1);
[sz1 sz2]=size(A1)

figure(2);[P,h1]=imcontour(A1,1);
```

this detects the contour, but function imcontour produces an additional small amount of points completely unrelated to the contour, and quite far away

```
hold all;
plot(P(1,:),P(2,:),'r*')  % check
```

[image]

2.- quik-fix for imcontour producing a few points far away.

```
Px=P(1,:);Py=P(2,:);
nx_out=find(Px>sz2)
P(:,nx_out)=[]
ny_out=find(Py>sz1)
P(:,ny_out)=[]
hold all;
figure(3);plot(P(1,:),P(2,:),'r*');axis ij  % check
```

[image]

3.- generating image with the complete contour only and 1 pixel thick contour only

```
Px=P(1,:);Py=P(2,:);
A2=zeros(sz1,sz2)
P=floor(P)
for k=1:1:numel(Px)
    A2(Py(k),Px(k))=255;
end
figure(4);imshow(A2)
```

[image]

4.- Selecting right hand side edge only

```
P2=[0;0]
for k=sz1:-1:1
    L1=A2(k,:)

    if sum(L1)>0
        nL1=find(L1>0)
        P2=[P2 [k;nL1(end)]];
    end
end
P2(:,1)=[]

figure(5);
imshow(A2);
hold all;

for k=1:1:length(P2)
    plot(P2(2,k),P2(1,k),'r*')  % check
end
```

[image]

The result can be improved refining the way pixels are selected, instead of

```
P2=[P2 [k;nL1(end)]];
```

using

```
P2=[P2 [k;nL1(2:end)]];
```

but this is assuming that the excluded left edge is a fairly straight up line, that may not be the case.

For more complicated shapes, to first find the single pixel thick contour
 have a look at my answer: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/350136-how-t-oget-straight-edge-in-binary-image?s_tid=srchtitle

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your arrows correctly:

This looks pretty straightforward: Just take every image row separately. Start from right until you hit a transition of value. Those positions are your border.

Comment: I will try and then get back..